# Don't have the "include navigation controller" option when making a new project in android studio 3.4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

When am creating a new Android Studio project, I do not have the option to "**include navigation controller**" as shown in this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@er.ankitbisht/mvvm-model-view-viewmodel-kotlin-google-jetpack-f02ec7754854) [image](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*_42vC8BkEnsFme0s0MomKg.png).

I'm using the Linux ubuntu `18.04` with `3.4.1` version of Android Studio with kotlin. I tried to search but i found nothing about it. Only the same question in [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/bde7aq/dont_have_the_include_navigation_controller/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Navigation Editor was an experimental feature in Android Studio 3.2. To enable the Navigation Editor (AS 3.2), click `File > Settings (Android Studio > Preferences` on Mac), select the Experimental category in the left pane, check the box next to Enable Navigation Editor, and restart Android Studio.

But it is not experimental feature anymore, its included in AS 3.3 version. Checkout out [Android Studio release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/)

To add a navigation graph to your project, do the following:

1. In the Project window, right-click on the res directory and `select New > Android Resource File`. The New Resource File dialog appears.
2. Type a name in the File name field, such as "nav_graph".
3. Select Navigation from the Resource type drop-down list, and then click OK.

When you add your first navigation graph, Android Studio creates a navigation resource directory within the res directory. This directory contains your navigation graph resource file (nav_graph.xml, for example).

[Checkout the official documentation here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started)